# Proving the existence of nonzero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Problem: Prove that if the matrix $A$ has two rows the same, then there exists a non-zero matrix $B$ such that $BA = 0$?

My progress in the solution. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{{m\times n}}$. I realized that if $B$ is a matrix such that it has $k$ rows of the form \begin{pmatrix}
u & -u & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...\\
\end{pmatrix}

Where $u \in \mathbb{R}$, then $BA=0$ ($BA \in \mathbb{R}^{{k\times m}}$). But it surely isn't a "proof" but an example? How do I proof the existence of such matrix?

Comment: You just proved the existence by constructing such a matrix $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume an equivalent statement: that $A^{T}$ has two same columns.

Then its columns are obviously not linearly independent i.e.

$A^{T}$ does not have full rank which implies that it has a non-zero nullspace. i.e.

There is a vector $v\neq\,0$ such that $A^{T}v=0$.

Now consider the matrix $C=[v\,0\,0..0]$ where the first column is $v$ and all other columns are zero.

Then $A^{T}[v\,0\,0\,...0]=0$. Taking transposes we get $C^{T}A=0$ and clearly $B=C^{T}$ is not a zero matrix.

Comment: Why transpose everything? Why not just let $v$ be a non-zero row vector with $vA=0$?

Comment: I agree! I just like columns better! It is easier to multiply matrices by columns!